# Simulate websocket connections

Tags: javascript, websocket, simulation, load-testing

I'm trying to determine the concurrent connections which can be handled by my server which is built on Websockets.

How do I perform such a simulation?
Are there are tools which specifically help in such a stress test?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603998/how-to-do-load-testing-for-websockets

Comment: Ahh thank you. I'm checking the answers.