# Make thousands of connection to websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have node js app with websocket
And deploy on ubunto service i want to know how may connection can this server handed before ram and cpu full
Is there any tool to make thousands of connect and manage it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603998/how-to-do-load-testing-for-websockets

Comment: [Websockets and scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268038/websockets-and-scalability/47269221#47269221).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603998/how-to-do-load-testing-for-websockets